# Site for question about feminism

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

### What site should this question be posted on?

I've seen [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_feminism):

> Radical feminism is a perspective within feminism that calls for a radical reordering of society in which male supremacy is eliminated in all social and economic contexts, while recognizing that women's experiences are also affected by other social divisions such as in race, class, and sexual orientation.

What does this 'radical reordering' include? It is not socialism (as radical feminist aren't Marxist feminist).

Comment: There is the philosphy stack which has a tag for feminism. I do not use that stack so cannot say whether your precise question falls within its remit.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be submitted on the philosophy SE with the feminism tag. It cannot go to the politics SE with the feminism tag.

Comment: I have posted it on Philosophy SE https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78489/what-is-radical-feminism/