# About finding a Stack Exchange society for empowering a women's rights society

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a member of a [Clubhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clubhouse_(app)) club which is working on feminism and social support for women and girls in a traditional society. In this club people have friendly discussions about the societal problems of Iran and share their view points for solving these problems.

The leader of this club is a lovely girl who gives us valuable energy and time to take care of the club members.

During the months I have been in this club, I have seen her attempts to help people and give them information, but I know managing a 1k member club is so hard and, as women's rights activities in the dictatorial government of Iran, I have seen some threats and pressure on her network and friends, especially those residing in Iran.

So if possible, I need to find some SE site to ask about useful strategies for empowering her network, to decrease the pressure on her and give new resources and backups as support for women's social activities.

One of these support is finding some English community to ask questions about those challenges.

Also, if possible, I would like to know about other alternative Internet websites instead of SE sites.

Comment: The sentence with *"One of these support is finding"* is partly incomprehensible. E.g., is a word missing?

Comment: "ask about useful strategies for empowering her network" It's not 100% clear what this all includes? Maybe add a few more details what kind of areas this empowering touches upon.

Comment: Duplicate?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359419/282094 - see also:  https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/social-network-tag

Answer (score 15):

We have a site dedicated to [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/) which might be a good fit. Please check their [Help Center](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to make sure it fits, and it's best to avoid questions which are [too open ended](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). And it's [one of the quietest sites in the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), so don't be too disappointed if you don't receive a good answer.

Comment: I'd thought it was slightly concerning if the site for questions about building communities has one of the least-active communities...  but [apparently it does have a solid core of members and moderators](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1373/1600) and its [answer rate is "excellent"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52070/moderators). So it seems to be fine, but just gets very few new questions.

Answer (score 2):

The whole [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is open to you.

Money questions could be asked on https://money.stackexchange.com, for legal issues on https://law.stackexchange.com, for travel issues on https://travel.stackexchange.com, for programming on Stack Overflow, for information security on https://security.stackexchange.com.

There are also sites about psychology (https://psychology.stackexchange.com), interpersonal skills (https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) or everyday life hacks (https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com). There is a site about politics (https://politics.stackexchange.com) and they have an activism tag.

And for education there is for example https://matheducators.stackexchange.com.

I could imagine them all to be helpful for you to overcome the challenges you might face. The best is probably to use them all.

However, the question must always be on-topic on the respective site and typically the community aspect of the single sites is not so emphasized. It's more transactional, like question and answer to question only. The chat functionality on the respective sites might more closely resemble a community...

Comment: Sorry but can't see how questions about a building a community can be on topic in most SE sites, except Community Building which is already answered. You just send the OP for a wild goose chase.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Empowering a network can have many aspects like legal, financial, information security etc. If you do not believe me, let's try to ask the OP in some time from now how helpful the number of SEs that I mentioned (which is a very limited selection of all SEs) were.